# javascript btoa function not working properly

Tags: javascript, html2pdf

I am using [this](https://github.com/eKoopmans/html2pdf.js/blob/master/README.md) html-pdf library to convert my html file to PDF. I am also sending the PDF file to the server by first converting into base64 string and sending it to a post route via ajax.

```
 html2pdf().from(element).set(opt).outputPdf().save().then(function(pdf) {
     //This logs the right base64
                 newpdf=btoa(pdf);
                 console.log(newpdf)
                 $.post('./setup', {payload: newpdf}, function(result) {
                 console.log('done');
   });
```

I know that the html2pdf function is working properly because I see the PDF downloaded in my browser which looks good. However,

```
console.log(newpdf)
```

should give me long list base64 characters but only gives me a small string like

```
dW5kZWZpbmVk
```

I am not sure why `btoa(pdf)` is not working properly

Comment: `dW5kZWZpbmVk` is `undefined` in base64 - now all that remains is for you to figure out why `.save` returns a promise that resolves to `undefined` - what makes you think `.save` will return a promise that resolves to a PDF?

Comment: The string you are converting probably does not exist. And you need to make sure you pass a string to ***btoa***.   `var enc = btoa("http:/.pdf")`. Not an object.

Comment: Looking at the source code to that library, save definitely always returns a Promise that resolves as `undefined` - so you'll need to do what you want a different way

Comment: technically, btoa is working  properly, it is getting an argument that is `undefined` (as expected) and stringifying it and converting it to base64 :p

Comment: @JaromandaX `.....save().outputPdf().then( ... ` worked. Will you tell me your thought process behind why you thought this would work

Comment: yeah, I read the code wrong - which is why I removed that comment :p

Comment: No you solved my issue. I replaced `outputPdf().save().then()` then with `save().outputPdf().then` and it worked

Comment: but is it a PDF?

Comment: wait .... `html2pdf().from(element).set(opt).outputPdf().save().outputPdf().then` worked? If so, I can show you a way you don't need two `outputPdf()` calls - maybe

Comment: No The  line now is :  
`html2pdf().from(element).set(opt).save().outputPdf().then(function(pdf)`

Comment: oh, OK ... cool then

Comment: Curious as to the motivation to base64 encode it client-side, as that will generally make the file larger and take longer to transmit.

Comment: I am using Nodemailer on the backend which can transmit base64 encoded file